# Given an array of floats, produce unique combination of arrays with max length 3 that are equal to or greater than a given target

Tags: javascript, arrays, subset-sum

I'm looking to use JavaScript for the following, but anything else would do as long as the logic/algorithm is there.

I'd like to group a list of players into parties. Each party should do enough damage per second (DPS) to kill an enemy within a certain amount of time. A player can only be listed in one party. I expect there might be cases where some players are "left over" as they don't have enough DPS, or there are not enough slots in each party.

#### Example

> **Target Value:** 35.00
>
> **Party Limit:** 10
>
> **Input:** Array of Floats [5.00, 10.00, 15.00, 20.00, 25.00, 30.00, 11.50, 13.25, 10.25, 11.00, 12.00]
>
> **Output:** [[5.00, 30.00], [10.00, 15.00, 20.00, 25.00, 11.50, 13.25, 10.25, 11.00, 12.00]]

Edit: Adjusted the Party Limit to 10, originally said 2. I put 2 as I thought it would be easier to convey the question with simpler examples. I've also added in 5 additional values to convey the idea that a party size can vary. With a party limit of 10, and being given an array size of 12. The expected output would be two arrays with an optimal combination of players by DPS.

Also I made the output look like a 2D array which is what I imagined the output to look like, if there's something better, I'm all ears.

I don't have a strong background in this area, but I've taken a look at various sorting algorithm posts, and the closest thing I've come across would be [Wikipedia's article on the Subset Sum Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), but I'm having difficulty implementing it with my conditions.

Comment: is the party limit always `2`? Just asking, because it is not listed under the inputs.

Comment: Party limit is typically 10, but ideally I'd have it by dynamically set as a parameter passed to the function. I'll add it in, thanks for replying.

Comment: What do you define as 'an optimal combination' of players by DPS?  The combination where the most players are playing?

Comment: I was imagining it as most players playing, with less total number of parties. Meaning you'd have 10 players in each party if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the party limit is 2.

You can have 2 pointers or markers.Initially first should point to 0th index and the other one to last index.

You can refer this algo:

```
create a 2d array arr;
i=0;
while(last_pointer>=first_pointer)
{
   if( given_arr[last_pointer] < = target_value)  
         arr[i].push(given_arr[last_pointer])
         last_pointer--;

    if(given_arr[last_pointer]+given_arr[first_pointer] < = target_value)
         arr[i].push(given_arr[first_pointer])
         first_pointer++;

     i++;



}
```